# Calling Props in JSX Invokes Invalid Syntax Error

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a functional component that must render only if some variables are not empty. I want to incorporate the logic that determines whether the component renders or not directly within the component itself (to clean up the parent component).

The component render function exists as:

```
return(
    {
        props.var1 && props.var2 &&
        (<div ...
            </div>
        </div>)
    }
)
```

However, I get a syntax error pointing to the dot ('.') in `props.var1` with message:

```
Unexpected token, expected ","
```

If I remove `props.var1 &&`, I get the same error on `props.var2`.

Why is this happening and how can I circumvent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do conditional rendering based on a, well, condition, you should check for the condition and return null first:

```js
// DeMorgan's laws (!(a && b) is the same as !a || !b)
if (!props.var1 || !props.var2) return null;
```

Then return the stuff you want to render as usual:

```js
return (
    <div>...</div>
);
```

The error is occurring because the brackets (`{}`) make JS believe you are trying to return an object.